# How do I filter a datagridview by keyword?

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, oledb, filtering

I want search a keyword from a `Textbox` in access file with C# and `DataGridView`, my code is below but has problem with error "Missing operand";

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
bs.Filter = "select * FROM book WHERE onvan like '*" + textBox1.Text + "*'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't pass a complete select query as a filter for your `bindingsource`. Try this instead

```
bs.Filter = "onvan like '*" + textBox1.Text + "*'";
```

And check this link for more informations: [BindingSource.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).